# c# .cs file with http relative link in comment in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, comments

Let Say I have following C# project structure in Visual Studio

- Spec

  - UserStory1.html
  - UserStory2.html
- Tests

  - Test1.cs
  - Test2.cs

Now I want to connect my unit tests with Specification written in html in the following way

```
//http://../path.to.UserStory1.html#or_even_some_anchor
[TestFixture]
public class Test1
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {

    }        
}
```

That way when I CTRL+Clik on the link in the comment I can jump to the specification and see what should be really tested.
Problem is that I don't know how to do a relative path to html file included in the project.

- How can I do that?
- If not in standard VS, is there some plugin available that will enable this?

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think that in your case the [`<see/>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation tag would make the most sense, but [others are available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This would change your example code to be the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// This test does something
/// </summary>
/// <see cref="http://../path.to.UserStory1.html#or_even_some_anchor"/>
[TestFixture]
public class Test1
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest() { }        
}
```

I tested with http://www.google.com and it opened it in a new tab within VS. All of this is built into VS without any additional add-ons.